# How to check SDL condition variables is waiting or not?

Tags: multithreading, sdl, mutex, conditional-statements

I am writing a SDL multithread application. My application has some threads that waits for signal by using SDL_CondWait.

```
SDL_LockMutex(mutex);
SDL_CondWait(cond,mutex);
SDL_UnlockMutex(mutex);
```

When users exit, I want to wake up the threads to let the application exit. However, when I used SDL_CondSignal to signal the conditional variables, the application sometimes got errors.

```
SDL_CondSignal(cond);
```

I guessed that is because at that moment, the condition varialbe isn't waiting.

My question is how to check whether SDL condition variables is waiting ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
struct SDL_cond
{
    SDL_mutex *lock;
    int waiting;
    int signals;
    SDL_sem *wait_sem;
    SDL_sem *wait_done;
};
```

The `waiting` struct field holds amount of threads that the are blocked.
Also, if you want to wake up *all* threads, you should call `SDL_CondBroadcast`. `SDL_CondSignal` wakes up only *one* of the threads.